# how to break codes not using if else?

Tags: php

how to break codes not using if else?

please see my codes bellow:

```
// this is a.php
if(file_exists('overrides/a.php')){
    require('overrides/a.php');
}

// many codes bellow
// if there is ''overrides/a.php', the codes bellow will not excute. 
// but I don't what to use if(){}else{} to do it which like bellow codes

if(file_exists('overrides/a.php')){
    require('overrides/a.php');
}else{
    // original codes
}

// I want to do it like

if(file_exists('overrides/a.php')){
    require('overrides/a.php');
    // some codes here to break all codes after this in this php
}
// original codes


// notice: 
// if there is another all.php
require('a.php');
require('b.php');   // can not break b.php when break a.php
```

---

all.php

```
<?php

require('a.php');

echo 'hello';
```

a.php

```
<?php

echo 'kkk<br>';
exit();
echo '222';
```

will display:

```
kkk
not kkk hello
```

Comment: you want break code when meet if codition?

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand a word. You should probably edit the question and provide your definition of "break" and "codes". In any case, organising code flow with optional included files looks terribly complicated.

Comment: I am assuming you want to exit main program so use `exit()` or `return()`

Comment: Would be best if you write everything from scratch. Describe what you have, and what you expect. Make it clear what is what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all.php

```
<?php

require('a.php');

echo 'hello';
?>
```

a.php

```
<?php

echo 'kkk<br>';
return;
echo '222';
?>
```

will give

```
kkk
hello
```

Comment: exit() will break b.php if all.php require a.php and b.php

Comment: Can you use switch case ?

Comment: I don't want to change the orignal codes in a.php , I only what to do overrides adding code before orignal codes

Answer (score 0):

you can use ternary operator instead of if else as follows:

(condition)? statements1:statement2;

If condition is true then statement1 will be executed otherwise statement2 will be executed.

In your case you can replace

```
if(file_exists('overrides/a.php')){
    require('overrides/a.php');
}else{
    // original codes
}
```

by

```
(file_exists('overrides/a.php'))? require('overrides/a.php'):// original codes ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if(file_exists('overrides/a.php')){
    require('overrides/a.php');
}
```

use:

```
include('overrides/a.php');
```

It'll rise a warning rather than error if the file is missing. You can setup php to don't display those warnings.